# How can i Convert this simple async,await formatted code using Future and .then() in dart (Flutter)?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, async-await

Below the code snippet I was talking about:

```
void getlocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator()
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    print(position);
}
```

I need to write this function in terms of Future in Dart (Flutter).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Geolocator()
    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low).then(print);`

Comment: but actually whats wrong with `async` / `await` stuff? why do you need such simple example to be converted with `Future.then()`?

Comment: I was learning both of them. I was experimenting and trying to convert one to another.

Comment: aha, good luck with learning then ;-)

Comment: Thanks dude. Have lot to learn :-)

Comment: nice stuff: https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-futures-96937f831137

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it. This was my first post , got to say stack overflow is cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version of `future, then` method.

[Future](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-async/Future-class.html) - It is used to represent a potential value, or error, that will be available at some time in the future.

```
Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
  .then((Position position) {
    print('Latitude : ${position.latitude}');
    print('Longitude : ${position.longitude}');
  }).catchError((err) {
    print(err);
  });
```

**Note** : If you want your program to wait until the async function completes, then use `await` or else use `then`.